# Javascript array with for loop, returns only last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a `for` loop, that adds data into an `array`.
but when I `console.log` the array, it is full of the last item of the `for` loop!

Here is my code :

```
var materialsData = results[1].data, // results[1].data is a http.get return
ln = Object.size(materialsData),
materials = [],
material = {};
material['Product'] = {};

for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
    material.Product['Name'] = materialsData[i].Product.Name;
    material.Product['Id'] = materialsData[i].Product.Id;
    material.StartingDate = materialsData[i].StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-');
    material.Device = materialsData[i].Device;
    materials.push(material);
}
```

Comment: Where and how have you defined variable `material`?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. So every iteration, you are overriding same variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `material` in the `for` block. As Objects are passed by reference same `object` is updated and pushed to the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
    var material = {
        Product : {
            Name : materialsData[i].Product.Name,
            Id : materialsData[i].Product.Id,
        },
        StartingDate : materialsData[i].StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-'),
        Device : materialsData[i].Device
    };
    materials.push(material);
}
```

Additionally, You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var materials = materialsData.map(function(m){
    return {
        Product : {
            Name : m.Product.Name,
            Id : m.Product.Id,
        },
        StartingDate : m.StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-'),
        Device : m.Device
    };
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You are updating and pushing the same object reference again and again so the object holds the last element values. Instead, initialize the object holding variable inside the for loop beginning.

```
for(var i=0; i<ln; i++){
  // initialize the object
  var material = { Product : {}, Id : {}};

  material.Product['Name'] = materialsData[i].Product.Name;
  material.Product['Id'] = materialsData[i].Product.Id;
  material.StartingDate = materialsData[i].StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-');
  material.Device = materialsData[i].Device;
  materials.push(material);
}
```

---

Or directly define the object as the argument of push method without holding it to any variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
  materials.push({
    Product: {
      Name: materialsData[i].Product.Name,
      Id: materialsData[i].Product.Id,
    },
    StartingDate: materialsData[i].StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-'),
    Device: materialsData[i].Device
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed referencing the same object. For me the trick was to wrap the object in question around `JSON.stringify()` and then within the loop I call `JSON.parse()` on the resulting string to turn it back

```html
var materialsDataString = JSON.stringify(results[1].data), // results[1].data is a http.get return
ln = Object.size(materialsData),
materials = [],
material = {};
material['Product'] = {};

for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
    var materialsData = JSON.parse(materialsDataString)
    material.Product['Name'] = materialsData[i].Product.Name;
    material.Product['Id'] = materialsData[i].Product.Id;
    material.StartingDate = materialsData[i].StartingDate.replace("T00:00:00", "").split('-').reverse().join('-');
    material.Device = materialsData[i].Device;
    materials.push(material);
}
```

.