# for() Loop returns only last element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question already has an answer here: [Javascript array with for loop, returns only last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675574/javascript-array-with-for-loop-returns-only-last-element), but I haven't found an answer to my particular case! I am cloning a particular section of a form with input fields and each input field has a unique *id* and am using these ids in an array: `var arrayFields = ['streamsource','amountgen','running_cost','taxdue','periodrange'];` so that when I clone the parent div of this form fields, the IDs and name attribute of each input field, corresponding to the current element of the array above gets updated with the current increment value of the parent cloned container. Only the **name attribute** of the form field as well as the form field **ID attribute**, corresponding to the last element of the array is what is affected, and instead of incrementing only the corresponding form field, the **name, ID attribute** of all the form fields are replaced by the last array element + the parent cloned container increment value:

```
    var n = parseInt(cloned + 1);
    var nElement = $('.clone').clone().attr('id','clone' + n);

        for(var i = 0; i <= (arrayFields.length - 1); i++){
            nElement.find('.massive').attr('id',arrayFields[i]+n);
            nElement.find('.massive').attr('name','massive['+arrayFields[i]+n+']');
        }
```

How do I get this to work as it should?

Comment: This looks like it should work. Are you sure arrayFields has the correct values?

Comment: What is `arrayFields`??? Plus you should use `each`! What you do is each time you fetch all `.massive` elements an change their names!

Comment: you're always modifying all matching elements... that clearly isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: @MattSpinks i've gone throught my code to check if that's the case, but it isn't

Comment: @KevinB What am I doing wrongly, please?

Comment: everything i mentioned in that comment, of course.

Comment: So @MattSpinks; so basically what you mean is i should do something like `$('.massive').each(function(){...}?`

Comment: @aknessy, I think you mean to address ibrahim mahrir.

Comment: @aknessy still don't want to tell us what `arrayFields` containing!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir arrayFields is the array of element corresponding to the ID and name attributes of each form field i.e `var arrayFields = ['streamsource','amountgen','running_cost','taxdue','periodrange'];`

Comment: Can someone tell me why my question is being down voted?

Comment: Can you post an example of what your rendered HTML looks like? Are you dynamically creating elements, or do all these elements already exist and you're just trying to apply names and ID's to them?

Comment: @Santi I was simply cloning a DIV which acted as a parent to a bunch of form fields with IDs and name attribute corresponding to the array described by `arrayFields...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `each` to affect all of them like this:

```
var n = parseInt(cloned + 1);
var nElement = $('.clone').clone().attr('id','clone' + n);

nElement.find('.massive').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', arrayFields[index] + n)
           .attr('name', 'massive[' + arrayFields[index] + n + ']');
});
```

Comment: I have no idea why i never thought of this approach! Thanks @Ibrahimmahrir for saving me hours of stupidity!